# (C# WPF) I'm using 2 awaits in a loop and they're going all over the place

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

Here's the code I'm trying to make work:

```
public async Task PlayAudioAsync(int id)
{

    stop = false;
    while (!stop)  
            {
        music.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        music2.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        music.Play();
        if (id < 1)
        {

            await Task.Delay(16000);
            music2.Play();

            await Task.Delay(16000);
        }
        else
        {

            await Task.Delay(51200);
            music2.Play();

            await Task.Delay(51200);
        }
    }
    stop = false;
}
```

The first question that you'd ask first is probably that why am I using two music players? I want the end of the sound loops play as well, there's reverb effects and the notes fade smoothly.

The second loop should start after 16 seconds if id is 0.
The first loop should restart after 16 seconds is id is 0.
In this case, the id is 0.

### What happens?

First time they play as they should.
After that they either don't play at all or play at the same time.
After that they do the opposite of what they just did.
And so on...

Also this is my first post, so I **almost** know what I'm doing here...

Comment: While this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I get the nagging feeling that you may need to research `TaskCompletionSource`

Comment: What is the purpose of the delay?

Comment: The delay is for starting the loop at a specific moment, I don't want to just wait until the loop has played all the way through.

Comment: You lost me at *`starting the loop at a specific moment`*. You need to clarify that last comment

Comment: Oh... By loop I meant an audio loop, not a programming loop. Like how you keep hearing the same melody in a song.

Comment: You see, all of this is important information that should be in the original question to avoid all this confusion.

Comment: I can see. I think I've learned most of the basics now for asking for help :D

Comment: Make it complete by showing how you call this, from the toplevel (event) on down. What type is `music` and is that Play() blocking?

Comment: I just realised, by changing the media source it sets the position to 0 but doesn't stop it from playing. That's what went wrong here, it was another piece of code changing the source.